# Problem access url variable end with equal sign

Tags: java, android, variables

I have a class in android studio and i using volley with request get method to access url.I have  no ideas why i cant access variable end with equal sign. Here is example:

Example 1 : this works

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://example.com/video/?id=123",
                    response -> {  ///RESPON OK
```

Example 2 : This not works

```
String url = "https://example.com/video/?id=";
 String id = "123";
 
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url+id,
                    response -> { /////NO RESPON
```

Example 3 :
I remove the equal sign

```
 String url = "https://example.com/video/?id";
 String id = "123";
 
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url+id,
                    response -> { /////It works
```

Comment: That can't be right, since examples 1 and 2 produce an equivalent string before the StringRequest constructor gets called

Comment: have you tried String.format() ?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, `+` operator on String is just a concatenation and there are no gotchas unless you have encountered a JVM bug.

Comment: Just curious, if you add a new variable in Example 2:  String newUrl = url + id; and call StringRequest with newUrl, what happens ?

Comment: Same,problem still exist.The probelm is equal sign inside the variable string.By the way i have solution , i put and sparate "=" from variable string. So like url + "=" +id; and its works.